# Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: Column cannot be null (BUT it isn't null...)

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, prepared-statement, fgetcsv

I'm getting a fatal error every time my PHP script is run. Despite that, all of the data is still uploaded to the database. When `$values[0]` is echoed, there are no `NULL` values as the error states, and everything is normal. I'm quite confused.

## Error

```
[02-Oct-2018 19:59:54 America/Vancouver] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home1/antonfa1/public_html/trading-history/process.php on line 22
[02-Oct-2018 19:59:54 America/Vancouver] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'trade_date' cannot be null in /home1/antonfa1/public_html/trading-history/process.php:48
Stack trace:
#0 /home1/antonfa1/public_html/trading-history/process.php(48): PDOStatement->execute(Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home1/antonfa1/public_html/trading-history/process.php on line 48
```

The strange thing is that I didn't seem to be getting this warning and error yesterday, so I commented out all of the modifications that I had made since then, but the issue persists.

## Script

```
include 'includes/connect.php';
$stri = 'INSERT INTO trades (trade_date, trade_time, trade_datetime, trade_transaction, trade_symbol, trade_status, trade_quantity, trade_filled, trade_price, trade_value) VALUES (:date, :time, :datetime, :transaction, :symbol, :status, :quantity, :filled, :price, :value)';

$file = fopen($_SESSION['file'], 'r');

while (!feof($file)) {
    
  $values = [];
  
  foreach (fgetcsv($file) as $key => $value) {
    array_push($values, $value);
  }
  
  echo $values[0] . '<br>';
  
  $stat = $conn->prepare($stri);
  $stat->execute([
    'date' => $values[0],
    'time' => $values[1],
    'datetime' => $values[2],
    'transaction' => $values[3],
    'symbol' => $values[4],
    'status' => $values[5],
    'quantity' => $values[6],
    'filled' => $values[7],
    'price' => $values[8],
    'value' => $values[9],
  ]);
}
```

Is `fgetcsv($file) as $key => $value` really an invalid argument? Is this what's potentially causing this "false" error? I wasn't getting this warning yesterday :/

## Echo

```
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
2018-10-02
```

All of the data points are there and none are `NULL`...

Comment: _"Is fgetcsv($file) as $key => $value really an invalid argument?"_ <- it is when it [returns `false` due to it being at the end of the file](http://php.net/manual/function.fgetcsv.php#refsect1-function.fgetcsv-returnvalues). This is something you need to check for when using `fgetcsv()`

Comment: @Phil why would a `foreach` loop execute after reaching the end of the file tho?

Comment: Because you're telling it to.

Comment: @Phil in the while loop, correct?

Comment: Have a look at the example ~ http://php.net/manual/function.fgetcsv.php#refsect1-function.fgetcsv-examples. You can (and should) use `fgetcsv()` in the same way you're using `feof()`

Comment: @Phil so with a `while` loop. but can i still use `as $key => value` like `while (fgetcsv($file) as $key => $value) ...`?

Comment: FYI, MySQL has a specific tool for importing CSV data which might be easier to use. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html

Comment: @Phil not sure if thatll help since a python script is uploading the csv file to my server and then automatically processing it once its been uploaded

Comment: Just thought I'd mention it

Comment: @Phil i appreciate it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that `fgetcsv()` returns `false` when it reaches the end of the file...

> **fgetcsv()** returns **NULL** if an invalid handle is supplied or **FALSE** on other errors, including end of file.

You can use `fgetcsv()` in the same way you're using `feof()` to only loop while there are records to be found.

For example

```php
$stri = <<<_SQL
INSERT INTO trades (
  trade_date, 
  trade_time, 
  trade_datetime, 
  trade_transaction, 
  trade_symbol, 
  trade_status, 
  trade_quantity, 
  trade_filled, 
  trade_price, 
  trade_value
) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
_SQL; // note the positional placeholders

$stat = $conn->prepare($stri); // prepare once, not in a loop
$file = fopen($_SESSION['file'], 'r');

while($values = fgetcsv($file)) { // EOF will return false and exit the loop
    if (count($values) === 10) {
        echo $values[0] . '<br>';
        $stat->execute($values);
    } else {
        echo 'Skipping invalid record';
    }
}
fclose($file);
```

If you use positional placeholders, you don't need to construct an associative array for the prepared statement.

Comment: dont know who voted u down. ill try that right after i finish trying to example in the php doc that u linked

Comment: k so ive got a working version from the manual `while (($row = fgetcsv($file)) !== FALSE) { $num = count($row); for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) { echo $row[$c] . "<br />\n"; } }`

Comment: @Anthony I've updated my answer to add some more checks, eg 10 records in the `$values` array

Comment: is it really necessary to format the value of the `$stri` variable like that?

Comment: @Anthony no, that's just using [HEREDOC](http://php.net/manual/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax so it formats nicer in my answer. Nothing special, you can use a plain old quoted string literal.

Comment: k im just gon try implementing this by only preparing the statement once and ill mark this as the answer once im done!

Comment: in ur while loop, `$values[0]` returns the whole row as an array, correct? so that i can access individual items like `if ($values[3] === 'Buy') ...` ? i really need to set up a way so that i can test php locally lol

Comment: No, `$values` is the current row values as an array. Say your row is `a,b,c,d`, the resulting array will be `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`. `$values[0]` would be `'a'`, `$values[3]` would be `'d'`

Comment: beautiful. thanks so much for ur help!!! really appreciate it. disappointing that somebody would down vote the actual answer, but kind of typical of SO lol

Answer (score -1):

Your PDO parameters need to be passed like this:

```
$statement->execute([
    ':foo' => 1,
    ':bar' => '2001-01-01',
    ':baz' => 42
 ]);
```

You are missing the `:` part of the key passed to `PDOStatement::execute`

Comment: The colon is not required. PHP will insert it for you if it's missing

Comment: See the source code ~ https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/pdo/pdo_stmt.c#L348